# Making a request for an URL and run in background in c++

Tags: c++, shell, url

I need to run a program in c++ for a long period of time that is making url requests on my site every 12 seconds, which triggers a php script. I figured out how to do the running, but every time it's making the "request", the browser pops up. You can't do anything while this program is running. So my question is: can I make the request for the page somehow so the browser didn't pop up? (My os is windows).
That is the c++ function that I'm using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://www.google.com/",NULL, NULL, SW_MINIMIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `open` uses whatever association is configured into the shell, by default it's a browser for URLs. Use a commandline HTTP client like wget or curl instead.

Comment: Or the windows http API (start with WinHttpOpen and go from there).

Comment: Don't use a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 3rd party http client with a C++ API like curl should work nicely for what you need.  You can find the documentation on their [website](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/).  Here is some very basic example code to make a URL request. You could just put it in a loop with a timer.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode res;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now there flags up another question. How can I have curl library locally? Because I need to send this program to multiple users so they could run it. In unix is so simple. You just write in your makefile all binaries that you want to compile and done. But how should I do it in windows?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio you could specify `/MT` to statically link your executable so that the statically linked curl library and C++ runtime will be included within your .exe file.  Here is the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx.